# How to assigne a cv::Scalar to cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

Using the class Scalar implemented in OpenCV, I didn't understand what is the difference between this code:

```
Mat test;
test = Scalar::all(0);
```

and this:

```
Mat test = Scalar::all(0);
         ^
```

My question is why is the first assignment correct while the second is not?

Comment: Do they both compile? I prefer the first, but I think the second would compile.

Comment: The first compile, the second don't. And rafix07 answered this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaration of `Mat` constructor which takes `Vec<_Tp,n>` as parameter is

```
  template<typename _Tp, int n>
  explicit Mat(const Vec<_Tp, n>& vec, bool copyData=true);
```

`cv::Scalar` is treated as `Vec<_Tp,4>` so you can pass `Scalar` to `Mat` constructor in **explicit** way `Class obj(parameter);` not `Class obj = parameter;` so call

```
Mat test(Scalar::all(0));
```